# Mejorar la descripción de la medalla "Promotor"

Tags: discusión, estado-completado

Gané la medalla **Promotor** al momento de ofrecer una recompensa en una pregunta que realicé, por lo que me parece raro que la descripción de la misma sea:

> Primera recompensa que otorgas en tu propia pregunta.

Casi parecida a la medalla **Benefactor** que se gana al momento de darle la recompensa a alguna respuesta:

> Primera recompensa que otorgas manualmente en tu propia pregunta.

En este sentido, la medalla **Promotor** no debería ser:

> Primera recompensa que ofreces en tu propia pregunta.

Comment: Creo que sí. Y quizás [Benefactor](/help/badges/47/benefactor) podría ser `Primera recompensa con la que premias voluntariamente en tu propia pregunta`... La decisión que se tome debería también aplicar a [Inversor](/help/badges/45/investor) y [Altruista](/help/badges/48/altruist).

Comment: Tienes razón, esas medallas también deben tenerse en consideración si se cambiara la descripción de las otras, yo pienso que la medalla promotor si se debería cambiar, se me hizo confusa esa descripción en base a como realmente se la gana.

Comment: Juan: veo que ya se completó el cambio. Edité mi respuesta indicándolo. ¡Gracias por plantearlo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veo que esto está en [estado-completado](/questions/tagged/estado-completado), pues Konamiman así lo reportó en [mi respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/1390/revisions) a *Sugerencias de mejora en las traducciones*. Y efectivamente, en la página de la medalla [Promotor](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/46/promoter) ya aparece:

> Primera recompensa que **ofreces** en tu propia pregunta.

---

Estoy de acuerdo.

Estas medallas se dividen en dos grupos: ofrecer y entregar la recompensa. Por tanto, debe quedar más claro que unas es por decir "ey, si alguien se lo *curra* recibirá una recompensa" y en las otras "ey, te lo has *currado*, aquí tienes la recompensa".

Desglosémoslo:

## Ofrecer recompensa

### [Inversor](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/45/investor) ✓

La versión inglesa dice:

> Invesor: First bounty you offer on another person's question

Y la española:

> Inversor: Primera recompensa que ofreces en la pregunta de otra persona

Creo que se entiende bien.

---

### [Promotor](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/46/promoter) ✖

La versión inglesa dice:

> Promoter: First bounty you offer on your own question

Y la española:

> Promotor: Primera recompensa que <s>otorgas</s> en tu propia pregunta

Mejorémosla a:

> Promotor: Primera recompensa que **ofreces** en tu propia pregunta

De esta forma se entiende mejor y mantiene el redactado de la medalla *Inversor*.

## Entregar recompensa

Aquí se optó por el verbo [otorgar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RKz1rM9). Me parece bien, aunque lo mismo [entregar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=FltFypa) sonaría mejor (siempre oigo *la entrega de medallas*).

### [Altruista](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/48/altruist) ✓

> Altruist: First bounty you manually award on another person's question
>
> Altruista: Primera recompensa que otorgas manualmente en la pregunta de otra persona

---

### [Benefactor](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/47/benefactor) ✓

> Benefactor: First bounty you manually award on your own question
>
> Benefactor  Primera recompensa que otorgas manualmente en tu propia pregunta

Comment: +1 .. Personalmente optaría por cambiar "manualmente" por "voluntariamente".

Comment: @Mariano mmm no sé. Una recompensa la otorga manual/voluntariamente  quien la abrió; si no la entrega y se cumplan ciertas condiciones, se otorga _automáticamente_ a una de las respuestas. Por tanto, veo bien usar _manualmente_ para marcar el contraste con_automáticamente_, cosa que se pierde con _voluntariamente_ (no tendría sentido _involuntariamente_).